# Android, Sending data between a Database

Tags: php, android

I need to be able to send a number(int) from phone1 to the database and another number from phone2 to the database. phone1 will then read phone2's number from the database and vice versa. Phone2 will also need to send its current location to the server.

The problem I am having is being able to send the data to my database. I have a database and web space for hosting php.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

I have tried using the webservice as seen in my below code, however nothing its being added to the database and I am unsure of what I have done wrong.

AsyncTask for posting data

```
class task extends AsyncTask<Integer, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... _gNum) {
        String sNum = String.valueOf(gNum);

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://mayar.abertay.ac.uk/~*****/Insert2.php");
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        try{
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone1", sNum));

            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        }catch(Exception e){}

        return null;
    }

}
```

php code - Edited

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("lochnagar.abertay.ac.uk", "*****", "*****");

mysql_select_db("*****", $con);

mysql_query($con "INSERT INTO hidenseek (phone1) VALUES("$_REQUEST['phone1'].")");

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I think the error lies with my php. However I cant for the life of me figure it out.

Thanks for all the help so far its been very useful.

Comment: You require a **Web service** which acts as an intermediate tool between device and remote database.

Comment: (insert the usual spiel about deprecated APIs and all that)

Either your code sample is incomplete or you forgot to add a statement to execute the query. See `mysql_query` and `mysql_select_db`

Comment: you can always check whether the value is getting in to the server side. If the mysql table doesn't contain the value you are not passing, just try to write the same in to a local file. Then you can understand whether its an issue with the webservice call from the mobile side.